# Why apt process() called two times in this situation

Tags: java, android, annotations

I am try to learn how to use annotation processor,but I face a problem that I find the `process()` method called two times.

```
src --
    com/ilumer/
               ExtractInterface(annotation)
               InterfaceExtractorProcessor(processor)
               Multiplier(.java)
```

`ExtractInterface`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ExtractInterface {
   String value();
}
```

`InterfaceExtractorProcessor`

```
 @SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.ilumer.ExtractInterface")  
 public class InterfaceExtractorProcessor extends AbstractProcessor { 
       public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv){
          System.out.println("Hello World");
          return false;
       } 
}
```

`javac com/ilumer/InterfaceExtractorProcessor.java` and `javac -processor com.ilumer.InterfaceExtractorProcessor com/ilumer/Multiplier.java`

the output

`Hello World`

`Hello World`

I am try find some solutions with google and oracle doc but fail to find any solutions to solve this program. What’s wrong about my program.Can you tell the progress about `Processor` with `javac`.

Answer (score 1):

I try to use `-XprintRounds` to find that this program has two rounds.

```
 round 1:
        : {com.ilumer.Multiplier}
        : [com.ilumer.ExtractInterface]
        : false
hello world
com.ilumer.Multiplier
round 2:
        : {}
        : []
        : true
hello world
```